# JS: Changes to JS files in chrome dev tools are not reflecting

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, debugging

I am trying to edit a JS file in chrome dev tools and half the time it works but the other half of the time the server JS file is cached and it used that, despite my changes.

I am trying to test a production feature only so I need to test it this way -- is there a way to ensure I can edit the chrome JS files so that it reflects each time in browser when testing?

Comment: Try [Local Overrides](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2018/01/devtools#overrides). Specific to Chrome tho.

Comment: Alternately, you could turn on "disable cache" in the network pane and then use a program like [Charles Proxy](https://www.charlesproxy.com/) or [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to point a given request to a file on your local machine.

Comment: thank you both.  @pmkro I went with Local Overrides -- thank you, I had no idea this existed!

Comment: @herkypam posted my response as a more detailed answer, might be useful for others in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chrome has a feature called [Local Overrides](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2018/01/devtools#overrides), which is basically this. It allows you to use a file location from your computer to load the webpage assets from, which you can modify, and the modifications will persist. Once you turn off the feature, it will revert to what is being served from the pages host (or cache), but you can re-enable and continue on.

As a word of note, this is only available (as far as I know) in Chrome V65+

[Chrome 65 Release Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D1pV7ermy6w)